# Identifying "how far away" and "how big" things look to an observer in a given metric tensor's space

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, visualization

Let's say I have a 2D spatial slice $h$ of a metric $g$, i.e., the $x,y$-components of $g$, and that there is a person, Alice, facing a rod that is oriented perpendicularly to the direction that she is facing.

I want to make statements about how far away and how big the rod appears to Alice. Normally, for $h = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, I could identify how far away the rod looks as the number of coordinate tick marks crossed between Alice and the rod, and I could identify how big the rod looks as the angle subtended by the rod, as calculated by the $\mathrm{atan2}$ function.

My question: Does this generalize to $h \neq \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Here are two quick examples of situations where the above identifications are non-obvious to me.

- For $h = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$, the rod will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$-times as many tick marks away from Alice along the $y$-axis as it is along the $x$-axis, if it is the same distance from Alice at both locations. Do I identify how far away it looks to Alice with distance from her, or with the number of coordinate tick marks crossed?
- For $h$ representing an elliptic geometry, the trusty circumference formula $C = 2\pi r$ no longer holds. For such a situation, can we still say that there are up to $2\pi$ radians to be subtended by an object, and does it still make sense to calculate angles using the $\mathrm{atan2}$ function?

The reason I ask this is that identifications like those above are useful to me when interpreting components of the metric tensor. I.e., if I see a metric tensor, I want to be able to think about how things appear to someone who lives in the space that it generates. But to be confident in interpreting things in this way, I want to know whether the above identifications are correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure whether or not that fits within the intent of my question, but it probably does, and so I'm interested in it. My real goal is to gain intuition on the meaning of different components of the metric. This question resulted from me trying to first think about the effect of the space components only, then including time components afterward. But if divorcing the components in that way doesn't work for even the simplest case (single observer, metric with constant diagonal components), then I suppose what you suggest would have to fit within the intent of the question.

Comment: To follow up a little more, in the case of the $h=(1,0;0,a)$ tensor, my initial thought was that the apparent distance away of the rod when it is distanced from the observer along the $y$-axis is $1/\sqrt{a}$ times that along the $x$-axis. I arrived at that from a calculation with spatial components only. If that calculation/interpretation (which I can type up as a response to my original post if desired), and a similar calculation for the apparent size of the rod, is flawed for the reason you suggest, then I think the ray-tracing approach would have to fall within the scope of my question.

Comment: The question how big things would look to the observer is nontrivial like Chiral Anomaly  already mentioned, analytical solutions are only known for very special cases. For example the observed shadow of a Schwarzschild black hole would have an apparent radius of √27 instead of 2 (GM/c²) for a stationary far away observer, but in general it is only straightforward to calculate the contracted size, which is different from the observed one, see http://raytracing.yukterez.net for a few examples and codes. If the observer is moving you also have to take aberration into account.

Comment: @user3558855 I'm doubtful your question is to be taken literally. Were it so it would a wrong approach. In order to understand metric tensor you don't need to know *how things appear to someone who lives in the space that it generates*.

Comment: @ user3558855 On the contrary you need to understand that coordinates without metric tensor are just labels with no physical meaning. Defining a metric tensor in a manifold enables to define
distances, angles, in one word a geometry and upon it a physics - different from the one we are accustomed in everyday world but well definite anyway. So please explain better your need, before I try an answer which could result misdirected.